# Cannot see physical/logical cores of newly added second quad-core when in Hyper-V manger

Tags: virtualization, performance, hyper-v

We have a DL380 G6 that was running with a single quad xeon. Since hyper-v is going well, we wanted to add more VM's. To keep things from bogging down, we added a second quad xeon to the box, and doubled the memory. When I create a new VM, logical cpu's only shows 1-4. I was expecting to see a choice of 1-8. When I look at task manager/Performance, there are 8 cpu's showing. Is there something in VM creation to pick physical cpu0 or cpu1?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/nickmac/archive/2008/07/04/hyper-v-rtm-maximum-supported-configurations.aspx):

> Virtual Processor support: Up to 4 virtual processors per virtual machine

So it seems that you may only be able to allocate up to four virtual processors per VM.